# Android RSS parsing - Google News RSS feeds are not "most recent" as opposed to search results. How to solve?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, rss-reader, google-news

1) Check this news output link:
www.google.com/search?q=example&num=10&hl=en&gl=us&authuser=0&tbm=nws&source=lnt&sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0CBUQpwVqFQoTCJi2r5XYl8gCFYeNDQodbDQF1g&biw=1242&bih=599&dpr=1.1

The parameters used are tbs=sbd:1, &tbm=nws&source=lnt - This SHOULD give you a time-sorted list of news. The most recent at the top. (Sorted by date as the parameter - sbd:1). However, when you click it, it goes back to sorted by relevance for some reason.
 Please check the meaning of URL tags here: https://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-search-url-request-parameters/

2) Now, check the corresponding RSS link: news.google.com/news/feeds?num=10&q=example&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=nws&source=lnt&output=rss

**Search for the title tag (in the above link) in your browser. You will note that the news stories have been REORDERED based on what Google calls "relevance" (even though sbd:1 is specified) . The most recent is NOT at the top.**

**Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to solve this? I want the most recent news titles at the top of the page on RSS. How to achieve this?!**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Strange! In my browser, adding &tbs=sbd:1 in the RSS feed's URL is ordering the items perfectly. Without it, problems occurs! Even when I push "num" to "30" for example!

http://news.google.com/news/feeds?num=30&q=example&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=nws&source=lnt&output=rss

Comment: No, click on the corresponding search link for for your query (not RSS). This will give you a "sorted by reference" output and not the last 24 hrs (or sorted by time). The top news in the link you post, was there 13 hours ago. The "time sorted" output has an article 26 mins ago. This is not a valid answer, sorry.

Comment: Tried another solution... without success, using the official Request Format page in Google's help. Adding &sort=date:D:S:d1 to the URL didn't change anything.
[link](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1077692)

Comment: I still can't figure it out. Any hints?